# image media and custom post type in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, posts

I am looking for some help / thoughts. I am building a travel site for a client who will continue to add content to the site when it is finished. At the moment there are 600+ images, just in one region, when the site is up and running there will be over 20 region's, and so a lot of images. Is there a way to section the images so that when the client wants images from the USA, that is all they see in the "Insert Media" window. I am using Custom Post Types for the sections. Does anyone have any thoughts and advice.

I would hope there is a plugin to achieve this, as to be honest I do not want to mess around with any core files in PHP.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you can separate images in post.
For example, Create one post USA and upload all USA region related images into it and there is one option in media to view all images from post.you can create multiple post for multiple region.

And Even you can fetch all images from single post too in wordpress.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there and thank you for the help.  Am I right in thinking the following... Go and do a new post called USA.  Upload all images.  When the files are uploaded click on the big X top right hand corner then there should be in the pull down menu Post USA.  Am I right?

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work in WordPress 3.5.1 unless I am doing something wrong.  Thank you, for your help so far.

Comment: pl refer link for example :http://creativedev.in/2012/11/get-all-images-from-single-post-in-wordpress/